# Robust Controls of Quadcopter

Tags: control, flight-controller

Can anybody please guide me about the robust modeling and control of a quadcopter. Where can i find the robust modeling that can be understandable for me as i am a undergraduate student. I am doing this in my FYP. Please suggest me some book that is written on robust modeling and control on quadcopter. Also, which uncertainties can we model? What are the best robust controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jr/2018/5607362/

Its not a book but its a very good paper.

I also recommend you to read some general robust Control and think about how would you do for a quadrotor

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sure I will.